# How to send RTMP video stream in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, rtmp

I'm working on living Stream to server in UWP using MediaCapture, but I can't find any useful solution about it.

Microsoft's library, but it only supports Azure.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AzureRTMPIngestLib

I can play RTMP live video streaming from server but can't send video streaming to server, I want to know if there has any solution or library can send RTMP live streaming in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

Following example below uses `STSP`. I've tested this example on a local network with using ipv4 addresses of two different computers. These computers are transmitting and receiving data at the same time to each other. Client and server sides of your app have to support the same protocol. And it gives too much properties about video recording and streaming processes.

**[Real-time communication sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication)**

> - A simple end-to-end video call client that demonstrates the low latency mode of the Windows Runtime capture engine. This is enabled using the msRealTime the video tag or RealTimePlayback on the MediaElement. The sample uses a custom network source and a custom sink extension to send and receive captured audio and video data between two computers.
> - A demonstration of the end-to-end latency of video captured using the Media Capture API and displayed using a video and MediaElement with low latency mode enabled. Two output windows are displayed. The first shows a camera preview window of the raw output from your camera. The second is a local host client window that shows the video from the camera when compressed, streamed, and received over machine's loopback network interface. This window demonstrates the end-to-end latency of video captured, streamed to, and displayed by a remote client minus network latency.

Now it's your turn. Please inform us about results.

Comment: If an answer consists primarily of an external link, it has little utility. Please include the relevant details from this link into the body of the question.